# warning when i am generating .jar

Tags: java, persistence

I have this warning:

```
   warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor
   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor' less than -source
   '1.7'
   Note: Creating non-static metadata factory ...
   Note: Found Option : eclipselink.canonicalmodel.use_static_factory, with value: false
   Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/orm.xml continuing with generation.
   Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml continuing with
   generation.
   Note: Found Option : eclipselink.canonicalmodel.use_static_factory, with value: false
   Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/orm.xml continuing with generation.
   Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml continuing with
   generation.
   warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor:
   '[eclipselink.canonicalmodel.use_static_factory]'
   Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
   1 warning
   Copying 5 files to E:\NetBeansProjects\votaciones\build\classes
   compile:
   Created dir: E:\NetBeansProjects\votaciones\dist
   Copying 1 file to E:\NetBeansProjects\votaciones\build
   Copy libraries to E:\NetBeansProjects\votaciones\dist\lib.
   Building jar: E:\NetBeansProjects\votaciones\dist\votaciones.jar
   To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
   java -jar "E:\NetBeansProjects\votaciones\dist\votaciones.jar"
   jar:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)
```

what happen?

Comment: Does your application work? If so, don't bother. It's entirely possible the annotation processor won't actually be bothered by the new features of Java 1.7. (Especially since it's a JPA processor, I don't think there were any changes to do with annotations in Java 7 that have any reason to throw it off.)

Comment: I'm guessing what happened is that you're using an annotation processor built for Java 6 on source code written in Java 7. I doubt it has any impact, but you're the person in the position to actually determine that.

Answer (score 0):

It says build was successful. The first warning is saying you use Java 7(1.7) where the source supports Java 6 (1.6). The second waring is a consequence of the first one. If your application works, i dont think there is any problem. If it doesnt work, try using java 1.6 or get the updated versions that support java 1.7.